# How can data be shared between a Windows store app and a Background task?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am creating a Windows store client that uses google services. I added a Background task (as a Windows Runtime Component) to update the app live tiles every 30 minutes. Problem is, I need to make a network call that requires a token. The token is available in the Windows store app's global variables and settings. How can I access it from the Background task?

Answer (score 1):

The UI app and the background task cannot share memory. The only way they can share data is by writing it out to application storage via **ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder**. However, that location is not secure and you should not write sensitive information like tokens or keys there.

I would recommend embedding the token in the Background Task project in the same way you embedded it in the UI project (usually as a resource or as a code constant).